# How many times per hand?

Tags: netilat-yadayim-washing

I've noticed that sometimes I see people washing Netilas Yadayim by washing once, twice, thrice, or four times per hand.

Is there any Halachic reason for this, or is it just a Minhag?

Comment: Shulchan Arukh and Rama say if you use at least 75 mL of water per pour you just need to wash once per hand.

Comment: Actually, I don't know if you are talking about washing before bread or not. So consider this closed as unclear in the meantime. There's definitely some dupiness in there somewhere.

Comment: one time if one uses a revvies and two times if not,however,the overwhelming practice is to do two times regardless